# How to get permutation group from one dimensional discrete data

Tags: combinatorics

when think this question, i search a matrix in a book related to permutation group
however do not know where this matrix come from.

What do A come from in page 318 of Enumerative Combinatorics Volume 2 in old edition
where A = [1,0,2; 0,2,0; 1,1,0];

using i,j of each value in A as coordinate to make permutation group

Comment: [Here](http://goo.gl/3ZWVQ)'s a link to that page. In the future, please either provide a link to freely accessible content or preferably give enough of the context to make the question self-contained.

Answer (score 1):

That $A$ doesn't come from anywhere. It is preceded by the phrase "for instance", which introduces an example that need not be derived from any other material.